# rails admin edit view path routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an admin section setup, but am having trouble getting the "update" route to work.

**Getting error when hitting "update" via the edit view:**
"No action responded to 2."

For some reason the route is responding to the :id as the :action.

**Parameters:**
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Update", **"action"=>"2"**, "_method"=>"put", "admin"=>{"ended_at(1i)"=>"2010", "ended_at(2i)"=>"8", "ended_at(3i)"=>"22"}, "id"=>"edit", "controller"=>"admin/subscriptions"}

The edit view uri:
/admin/subscriptions/2/edit

**Edit view:**

```
<% form_for :admin, @subscription, :html => {:method => :put} do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :ended_at %><br />
    <%= f.date_select :ended_at %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Update' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

**Route:**

```
  map.namespace :admin do |admin|
    admin.resources :subscriptions
  end
```

I assume I need to do something differently in the form_for method or maybe the routes, but everything I've tried isn't working.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be this:

```
<% form_for [:admin, @subscription] do |f| %>
```

By putting `:admin` and `@subscription` in square-brackets, this makes it into an array which is passed as the first argument to `form_for`. The benefit of this is if `@subscription` is a pre-existing record (as-in, one found by `find`, not created with `new`) then Rails will know to set the `form` method to `PUT`.

Comment: hmm. thanks! that works for another controller. for this one i'm getting a "show" action when doing that. not a big issue as i'm able to force the action, but it's not clean ;)

Comment: excelent! avoid me some problems

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
<% form_for :admin, @subscription, :html => {:method => :put}, :url => { :action => "update" } do |f| %>
```

Seems verbose though. Any better ideas?

Comment: Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543673/rails-admin-edit-view-path-routes/3543798#3543798

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
- form_for :subscription, @subscription do |f|
```

We're using formtastic here.

Comment: The `:subscription` is redundant? He's also namespacing the Subscription resource, so he'll need to use the Array form.